# Using the Material UI App Bar and React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm currently trying to build a website using react for my web development class, which is my first foray into JS and React. I'm using a Material UI appbar for my header. I've used react router in one of my class examples so I've set that up and my app bar is displaying as intended. My question is, how do I set the buttons on the appbar/header to link to my pages? The default code (minus imports) provided by Material UI is below with my placeholder page names added.

```
const pages = ['Utility List', 'Register', 'Login'];
const settings = ['Profile', 'Account', 'Logout'];

const Header = () => {
  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState(null);
  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState(null);

  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleOpenUserMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };

  const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="div"
            sx={{ mr: 2, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}
          >
            LOGO
          </Typography>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElNav}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
              onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
              }}
            >
              {pages.map((page) => (
                <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="div"
            sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}
          >
            LOGO
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
            {pages.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
            <Tooltip title="Open settings">
              <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Menu
              sx={{ mt: '45px' }}
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElUser}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
              onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
            >
              {settings.map((setting) => (
                <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
export default Header;
```

Answer (score 3):

Find the place in your code where your navbar links are added to JSX. Wrap each link in `Link` component from `react-router`

```js
const yourPages = [
  { text: 'Home', href: '/' },
  { text: 'About', href: '/about' }
]

// inside return statement
{yourPages.map((page) => (
  <Link href={page.href}>{page.text}</Link
)}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As "[answered by PYTHON DEVELOPER999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022486/using-the-material-ui-app-bar-and-react-router/72023898#72023898)"
But using `href` with react-router-dom is not optimal
Using `href` will cause the whole page to refresh, instead of just reloading the route.

Instead, use `useNavigate` from react-router-dom

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

// modify the OnClick handler to redirect Router
const handleCloseNavMenu = (to:string) => {
    navigate(to); 
    setAnchorElNav(null);
};

...


<Button
  key={page.text}
  // pass the href info to handler
  onClick={()=>handleCloseNavMenu(page.href)}
  sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
 >
  {page.text}
</Button>
```

Which should only change the routes inside `<Routes/>`, without refreshing the page.
Alternatively, use `<Link to="xxx"></Link>` from `react-router-dom`, but it will not follow the style of mui Typography.